# I launched a django server and now I can't stop the process

Tags: python, django

Can anyone please tell me how to stop my server? I did like the first few things you need to do in order to commence a django webpage, url pattern, request, HttpResponce etc. and I ran my server but that rocket is still showing on my screen despite trying to kill, pkill, ctrl+pause, ctrl+C.
I'm so done with this...
I looked up on The Internet how to stop my django server. Nothing worked. On top of that when I ran it I got a "ModuleNotFoundError" but the rocket is still showing when I type in the numbers...

Comment: can you add more details please  screenshot for exemple

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without a screenshot, we can only guess the issue.

I see you've tried some of the basic keybinds, have you tried CTRL+F4?

You could also kill the process.

`ps auxw | grep runserver`

This will return a process and the associated PID
`de        7956  1.8  0.6 540204 55212 ?        Sl   13:27   0:09 /home/de/Development/sampleproject/bin/python ./manage.py runserver`

then kill it with
`kill 7956`

Please make sure there are no &'s in your command as it may send it to the background.

Comment: I tried ctrl+f4 and it worked. You were very helpful. I'm new to all this and I'm trying to create a project with django and postgres. I have an understanding of OOP but even so I've been hitting some major roadblocks along the way so thanks again for pulling me out of this predicament.

Comment: Glad to be of help, I wish you luck in your learning. If you could mark my post as the answer so others can see if they have the same issue, that would be amazing.